# JQuery: conditional scripting based on viewport

Tags: jquery, conditional-statements, viewport

```
$("#ib1").delay(100).animate({opacity:.80},500);
$("#ib2").delay(200).animate({opacity:.80},500);

$(".indexbox1,.indexbox2,.indexbox3").hover(
    function(){
        $(this).animate({opacity:1},250);
        $(this).find(".indexboxtag").animate({opacity:1,bottom:20},200);
        },
    function(){
        $(this).animate({opacity:.80},250);
        $(this).find(".indexboxtag").animate({opacity:.5,bottom:10},200);
        }
    );
```

This is a section of my JQuery script that I want to disable/avoid when the viewport is under 1100px and thus being displayed on a touch device. How can I integrate that with window resize detection as well?

Comment: Don't depend on viewport-size to determine if the browser is on a touch-device. Actually check for touch using something like Modernizr.

Comment: Whether or not a user is on an actual touch device, if the viewport is 400 pixels wide I want the user to be viewing a website fit for 400 pixels wide. Modernizr will determine if it's a touch device but how would it disable JQuery functions?

Comment: `$(window).width()` gets the current width of the window, this dimension changes if the browser is resized. You can also base your conditional off of `screen.width` which is the screen resolution, not browser window size.